# jboss 5 stop start application without bouncing container

Tags: jboss

I'm using jboss 5 on solaris and have a simple question.

If a single server is hosting multiple web applications is it possible to stop/start/restart an individual application without bouncing the entire server from the jmx console/command line.

The setup we have at work is that each application is hosted by a different jboss instance, this was done as no-one knows how to stop/start individual apps without affecting the other. This doesn't make sense to me and creates additional load on the server. I know in glassfish you can do it through the admin console but the jmx console is not so user friendly to make this obvious to me

thanks sapatos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Go in admin-console at http://localhost:8080/admin-console to the respective web-app and then on the operations tab from where you can invoke start/stop/restart.
You can of course also do it in jmx-console.

Comment: thanks Heiko, I did a search on the admin-console and found the following which worked a treat: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RedeployFromTheJMXConsole
tested it on 4.2.2 on my PC and looks good. is there a more user friendly version of jmx-console? It made snese after reading this article but without it you're stuffed :)

Comment: Admin-console may not be in JBoss 4.2.2 (but I recall we had some 'EmbeddedJopr' in some late versions of JBoss 4